# Prefix euro sign in on edit EditText and remove it when doing getText()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to prefix an Euro sign as soon as a user starts typing in an EditText. This first thing is working. But the problem is as soon as I read it out in code it still has the euro sign. And I cant just remove the euro sign everywhere `getText()` is called. So what I want is to override the `getText()` inside this class. But the problem is that the `onTextChanged()` and  the `getText()` are starting a infinitive loop as soon as the user starts typing where they keep calling each other.

See code below:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

  ...


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(!s.toString().contains("€") && !s.toString().equals("")
                || s.toString().indexOf("€") != 0 && !s.toString().equals("")) {
            String replaced = s.toString().replace("€", "");

            String value = "€" + replaced;

            this.setText(value);
            this.setSelection(count + 1);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = super.getText();
        s.replace(0, 1, "€");


        return s;
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(AppConfig.LOGGING_TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        setTypeface(tf);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution which solves this problem inside the CustomEditText itself?

Comment: Use: `getText().toString().replace("€", "");`

Comment: please read the queston

Comment: `... and remove it when doing getText()`

Comment: Yeah which should be overridden inside the custom Edit text

Comment: But you can't call `setText()` inside `onTextChanged()` without getting an infinite loop. Because they call each other.

Comment: Then how should I set the text?

Comment: Well, you really should **not**. Let Android handle the text. Put the euro sign **outside** the EditText - could be an alternative solution.